# Basic conceptual questions about orthogonality in Linear Algebra,

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry, orthogonality, orthonormal

I have the Gram-Schmidt algorithm memorized, so that I can always compute an orthonormal basis, when I need it (on pen and paper, I don't studying mathematical / scientific computing ... yet).

Could I think of the Gram-Schmidt algorithm geometrically (algebraically, I am fine with the proof, but I have no geoemtric insight from it) in the two / three-dimensional cases?  How does...subtracting a bunch of inner products that scale vectors turn a linearly independent set into an orthogonal set?

Another orthogonality question I have is:  I know the formula to compute the orthogonal projection of a vector $\vec v$ onto some subspace $W$ is given by:

$$P_W(\vec v) = \sum \langle \vec v, u_i\rangle u_i$$

where $u_i$ is an orthonormal basis for the subspace $W$.

But, there is another orthogonal projection that I know of:

If I look at the operator given by this matrix multiplication

$$UU^t$$

where U has orthonormal columns (is an orthogonal matrix, if it is nxn square)

then we know that $UU^t$ represents orthogonal projection of vectors onto the column space of $U$.

Are these two orthogonal projections related?  Can they be used...interchangeably?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geometric interpretation of Gram Schmidt is as follows.  Given a subspace $S\subseteq \Bbb R^n$, you can always decompose a vector $v\in \Bbb R^n$ as the sum of a vector parallel to $S$ and orthogonal to $S$: $$v=v_\| + v_\bot$$

[image]

NOTE: This is the best picture I can find -- sorry that it's not great.  Hopefully you can see that the dark blue vector is being decomposed into the sum of the green vector parallel to the plane and the light blue vector orthogonal to the plane.

We can call these two vectors the *projection* of $v$ onto $S$ and the *rejection* of $v$ from $S$.  Gram-Schmidt is just the process of removing the projections of each vector onto the $1$d subspaces formed by the span of each of the previous vectors.

Let's see how it works for a $3$d subspace.  We're given a basis $\mathcal B=\{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$ of a $3$d subspace $S$ and we want to find an orthonormal basis $\mathcal E=\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ for $S$.

First we start by just setting $e_1 = \frac{1}{\|b_1\|}b_1$ -- that is we just take $e_1$ to be the unit vector in the direction of $b_1$.

Then for $e_2$, we first decompose $b_2$ into it's projection and rejection from $b_1$:  $$b_2 = {b_2}_\| + {b_2}_\bot$$ Then we see that the part of $b_2$ that's orthogonal to $b_1$ is given by ${b_2}_\bot = b_2-{b_2}_\| = b_2 - \operatorname{proj}_{b_1}b_2$.  This gets rid of the part of $b_2$ that's parallel to $b_1$, leaving only the part that's orthogonal to it.  Then we set $e_2 = \frac{1}{\|{b_2}_\bot\|}{b_2}_\bot$.

Then for $e_3$, we follow the same procedure.  We decompose $b_3$ into its parts parallel to and orthogonal to $\operatorname{span}(b_1, b_2)$: $$b_3 = {b_3}_\| + {b_3}_\bot = (\operatorname{proj}_{b_1}b_3 + \operatorname{proj}_{b_2}b_3) + {b_3}_\bot$$

Solving for ${b_3}_\bot$, we get $${b_3}_\bot = b_3 - \operatorname{proj}_{b_1}b_3 - \operatorname{proj}_{b_2}b_3$$  Then we just set $e_3=\frac{1}{\|{b_3}_\bot\|}{b_3}_\bot$.

Comment: Hi @Bye_World, thanks so much for this awesome write-up.  So it is nothing more than viewing each vector as a linear combination of a vector in the subspace and of a vector orthogonal to the subspace -- and then subtracting off the projections (what's lying on the subspace), and the remainder is the vector that is orthogonal to the space.   ... then these terms that show up in the G-S algorithm, say, for example $\frac {<w_k, v_j>}{||v_j||^2} \vec v_j$, is an orthogonal projection of $w_k$ onto the line spanned by $v_j$.  But why is the division by the norm-squared of $v_j$ necessary?  Thanks,

Comment: Look at [this image](http://blogs.jccc.edu/rgrondahl/files/2012/02/parallelprojection1.jpg) and remember that $\langle u, v\rangle = \|u\|\|v\|\cos(\theta)$.  Clearly $\|\operatorname{proj}_vu\| = \|u\|\cos(\theta)$ from our knowledge of trigonometry.  So if we want to get the projection of $u$ onto $v$ we just need to multiply that length by the unit vector in the direction of $v$.  That is $$\operatorname{proj}_vu =  \|u\|\cos(\theta) \left(\frac{1}{\|v\|}v\right)$$ Now just multiply that by $1=\frac{\|v\|}{\|v\|}$ to get back the usual formula for orthogonal projection.

Comment: Hi @Bye_World -- I've actually been reading your write-up several times to really make sure I understand what's going on; for the most part I do.  Can I just squeeze in one final question, if you don't mind?  Is the projection of $\vec v$ represented by $P_v = \sum<\vec v, u_i>u_i$ the same thing as the action of an orthogonal projection matrix $UU^t$?

Comment: They seem like different objects to me;  the first object projects vectors *not* already in the space...onto the space and the second is a projection of vectors already in the space ...to a subspace, namely, the column space of the orthogonal matrix, $U$.  What do you think?  They are both *orthogonal* projections ... not just arbitrary projections, so I do wonder whether both are the same thing in disguise and can be used interchangeably.

Comment: I doubt this is the case: for example if my projection matrix is $UU^t$, where $U$ has column vectors that form an orthonormal basis for the space of polynomials of degree at most 2, then ...applying $UU^t$ to a 3rd degree polynomial, $x^3$, doesn't really make sense.  What do you think?  Thanks @Bye_World,

Comment: Projection is an endomorphism.  That means that if $P$ is your projection operation then $P:V\to V$ for some vector space $V$.  So I don't know what you mean by projecting vectors in and out of the space.  Projections always project vectors in $V$ to some subspace of $V$.  Projection given by $P_v = \sum<\vec v, u_i>u_i$ and projection given by $UU^T$ are *practically* the same thing.  What I mean by that is technically the formula for $P_v$ works in *any* finite-dimensional real inner product space whereas $UU^T$ is only an operator on $M_{1\times n}(\Bbb R)$.  But there's a theorem that ...

Comment: says that all $n$-dimensional real vector spaces are isomorphic.  So if you're given a vector space $V$ and some projection operator $P_v$, then you can always convert that into a discussion of a projection operator on $M_{1\times n}(\Bbb R)$ given by $UU^T$ for some $U$.  As for your example with $x^3$, it doesn't make sense to try to project $x^3$ onto $\mathcal P_2(\Bbb R)$ unless you're considering $\mathcal P_2(\Bbb R)$ as a subspace of $\mathcal P_3(\Bbb R)$.  But if that's the case then when you convert to $M_{1\times n}(\Bbb R)$, then your $UU^T$ should be a $4\times 4$ matrix.

Comment: Hi @Bye_World ... I'm struggling with this a bit.  So, $UU^t$ is really only orthogonal projections onto one-dimensional subspaces, e.g., lines in $R^3$, right?  Then, with a 3x1 orthonormal basis column vector,$U$, $UU^t$ gives me the 3x3 projection matrix that projects 3x1 vectors onto this line (column space) of U.

Comment: Now, if I tried to project 3x1 vectors in $R^3$ to ...the column space of some U that is orthogonal (nxn square, not nx1), then it must be the vector itself, since $U$ orthogonal implies that $UU^T$ = $U^tU$ = $I$, the trivial projection.  So...basically, I know how to use $UU^t$ to project vectors onto lines.

Comment: Could I project $x^3$ onto the 3-dimensional subspace of polynomials of degree at most 2 ...using some matrix $UU^t$?  Would the U be ...a 4x4 matrix or a 4x1 matrix?  (I know that $UU^t$ will be 4x4, though.)  What would be the entries in this $U$?  I am guessing it must be a 4x1 matrix, or else as I mentioned above, we'd get the identity operator.  Then...what are the entries of this 4x1 matrix?

Comment: Should each entry be a *basis vector* of the polynomial space?  This seems nonsensical ... putting vectors ...into a vector entry.  What do you think?  I'm really trying hard to make the connection between formula # 1 and with the operator $UU^t$, thanks @Bye_World,

Comment: The $U$ matrix of course must contain all the information from the first 3 orthonormal polynomials ... so that $UU^t$ projects $x^3$ onto the column space of $U$ means that we are projecting $x^3$ onto the space of polynomials of degree at most 2, which is exactly what we wanted to do.  But how to construct this $U$, for some reason, is tricky ... @Bye_World,

Comment: If you still struggling with this ask it, with as much of your own thoughts as possible, as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I can give a pretty straightforward answer to the first part of your question - yes there is a visualisation in 2 and 3 dimensions.

The first part of Gram-Schmidt (GS) normalises the first vector in the set; that just means we scale it to length=1: 
$$\frac{v_1}{|v_1|}=u_1$$

Then we take the second vector, and take the dot product. Now, from your second question, I'm guessing you understand that the dot-product tells you `how much' one vector projects onto another. So then if you broke your second vector into components, it would be composed of a vector parallel to $u_1$ with the same length as the dot-product, and other components perpendicular to the first vector. So then considering $v_2\ -<u_1, v_2>\cdot u_1$ leaves you with something perpendicular to $u_1$ - you now have an orthogonal set.

To make it orthonormal, you just do step 1 again, scaling it so it has length=$1$.

An example helps: 
Consider $\{(1, 0), (2, 1)\}$ as your vectors. Clearly the first vector $v_1=(1, 0)$ is already normalised (scaled to have length=1), so we move to step 2. Using the standard basis for the plane, you can break $v_2=(2, 1)$ into two components that are perpendicular: $v_2=(2, 0)+(0, 1)$.

Now the dot product would have told you that the component pointing in the direction of $v_1$ had to be $<v_1, v_2>=2$, so by subtracting $2$ lots of $v_1$, we're left with a vector $u_2=v_1-2\cdot u_1=(0, 1)$. As this is also already normalised, you're done.

I hope this gives some insight; the generalisation to 3-D is straight-forward, you next subtract from $v_3$ the components that point in the same direction as $u_1, u_2$ and leave behind the orthogonal part. Note that you need linear independence, as otherwise $v_3$ would be in the span of $v_1, v_2$, and so subtracting these components would leave you with the zero vector - and that's not getting you any closer to an orthogonal set!

I'm afraid I can't answer your second question, but I know Paul R. Halmos has a pretty good discussion on projections and projective transforms in his book "Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces", which I can heartily recommend.

EDIT: There's an excellent visualisation on wikipedia.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: Thanks so much for your write-up and the Wikipedia link @AlexanderHeyes :-)

Answer (score 1):

As far as your second questions goes, they’re in fact the same thing!

First, I hope that you see the connection between Gram-Schmidt and the formula for orthogonal projection onto a subspace. The latter is simply the sum of the projections onto the individual basis vectors of the space, which is precisely what you compute at each step of the G-S procedure.

Now, let $U$ be the matrix $\pmatrix{\mathbf u_1&\mathbf u_2&\cdots}$, i.e., the matrix with the basis vectors of the given subspace as its columns. Then $$\begin{align}
\sum_i \langle\mathbf v,\mathbf u_i\rangle\mathbf u_i &= U\pmatrix{\langle\mathbf v,\mathbf u_1\rangle \\ \langle\mathbf v,\mathbf u_2\rangle \\ \vdots} \\
&= U\pmatrix{\mathbf u_1^T \\ \mathbf u_2^T \\ \vdots}\mathbf v \\
&= UU^T\mathbf v.
\end{align}$$

Note that this equality only holds for the Euclidean scalar product. The matrix operation expression for orthogonal projection relative to other scalar products is a bit more complicated.

Consider, for example, the space of polynomials of degree $\le3$ with real coefficients, with inner product $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{-1}^1f(t)g(t)\,dt$. Taking $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ as the basis, you can verify that this inner product is represented by the matrix $$
S=\pmatrix{
2&0&\frac23&0 \\
0&\frac23&0&\frac25 \\
\frac23&0&\frac25&0 \\
0&\frac25&0&\frac27},
$$ that is, if you represent elements of this space as vectors in $\mathbb R^4$, then $\langle f,g\rangle=g^TSf$. Relative to this inner product, an orthonormal basis for the space is $$\begin{align}
u_1 &= \frac1{\sqrt2} \\
u_2 &= \frac{\sqrt6}2x \\
u_3 &= \frac{3\sqrt{10}}4x^2-\frac{\sqrt{10}}4 \\
u_4 &= \frac{5\sqrt{14}}4x^3-\frac{3\sqrt{14}}4x
\end{align}$$ In the process of constructing this basis you had to find the orthogonal projection of $x^3$ onto the subspace of second-degree and less polynomials: $$
\langle u_1,x^3\rangle u_1+\langle u_2,x^3\rangle u_2+\langle u_3,x^3\rangle u_3 = \frac35x.$$ The matrix for orthogonal projection onto this subspace is given by $$\pi = UU^TS,$$ where $U$ is the matrix with columns $u_1,u_2,u_3$. The $S$ appears because of its role in the scalar product. A bit of tedious multiplication gives $$\pi=\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&\frac35\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0}.$$ You can see by inspection that this gives the same result for the vector $x^3$ as you got by computing the individual projections onto the unit vectors.

It turns out that you don’t even need an orthonormal basis. If the columns of $U$ are any basis for the subspace, then the orthogonal projection is given by $$
\pi=U(U^TSU)^{-1}U^TS.
$$ The extra term in the middle takes care of any normalization that might be required.

Comment: Hi @amd, thanks so much for your write-up.  The algebra makes sense...but last night, I worked on a problem where I had to project a 3rd degree polynomial, $x^3$, onto the space of polynomials of degree at most 2.  Using the L.H.S., this was straightforward -- just some tedious calculations with the specified inner product.  However, I also tried using the R.H.S., $UU^Tv$ to see whether both are the same, like you claim.

Comment: But...$UU^t$ doesn't seem to make sense in this context.  I mean...applying this 3x3 (orthogonal) projection matrix to the vector ... $x^3$ -- how does that make sense?  What is the 3x1 vector that would represent the polynomial $x^3$?  $x^3$ cannot be expressed as a linear combination of the basis vectors from the space that we are trying to project it to...  Thanks @amd,

Comment: Note that this identity only holds for the Euclidean scalar product $\langle\mathbf u,\mathbf v\rangle=\mathbf v^T\mathbf u$. With another scalar product, the matrix expression for orthogonal projection is much more complicated.

Comment: To your last point: you’re not trying to express $x^3$ as a linear combination of second-degree and lower polynomials. That’s clearly impossible. What you’re doing is decomposing it into the sum of two polynomials, one of which—the projection onto the subspace—is a linear combination of the lower-degree polynomials, and the other is orthogonal to them, where orthogonality is defined by the scalar product. You can see that for yourself by applying G-S to $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ with $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{-1}^1f(t)g(t)\,dt$: the last basis vector is a multiple of $x^3-\frac25x$.

Comment: Hi @amd, thanks so much for your additional comments; I spent all night thinking about and reviewing geometrically what G-S and orthogonal projections mean.  I also continued to struggle with making the connection between the first orthogonal projection formula and the matrix $UU^t$ - now I know that the specified inner product was the issue.  I am ready to move on now :-).   Thanks again and have a great, amd.   Hope to hear from you soon,

Comment: Oops. I had $Z$ when I meant $S$. My mental model for this stuff is solving electrical networks, where the inner product is determined by branch impedances $Z$. Fixed now.